# How to sign in for a Rspec request with new_user_session post?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I am writing a very simple test: is my page displayed when my users is logged in? I use a Factory to create the test user, and request to check the case:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  sequence(:login) {|n| "user#{n}"}
  sequence(:email) {|n| "user#{n}@gmail.com"}
  factory :user do
    playground_id       {0}
    default_playground_id {0}
    group_id            {0}
    first_name          {"user"}
    last_name           {"test"}
    user_name           {FactoryBot.generate :login}
    email               {FactoryBot.generate :email}
    password            {"DQtest_user01"}
    password_confirmation {"DQtest_user01"}
    description         {"This is a test User used for unit testing"}
    created_by          {"Rspec"}
    updated_by          {"Rspec"}
    active_from         {"2010.01.01"}
    active_to           {"2100.01.01"}
    confirmed_at        {Time.now}
  end
end
```

If logged in, the index template should be displayed, otherwise we are redirected to the sign_in form (based on Devise)

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe BusinessArea, type: :request do

  describe "Business Areas pages: " do
    context "when not signed in " do
      it "should propose to log in" do
        get "/business_areas/index"
        follow_redirect!
        expect(response.body).to include('Sign in')
      end
    end
    context "when signed in" do
      before do
        get "/users/sign_in"
        test_user = FactoryBot.create(:user)
        post "/users/sign_in", :params => { user_login: test_user.user_name, user_password: test_user.password}
      end
      it "should display index" do
        get "/business_areas/index"
        expect(response).to render_template(:index)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The form generated for login provides the following fields to Devise:

```
      <label for="user_login">Login</label><br />
      <input autofocus="autofocus" type="text" name="user[login]" id="user_login" />
      <label for="user_password">Password</label><br />
      <input autocomplete="off" type="password" name="user[password]" id="user_password" />
```

Running the test returns this message:

> Failures:
>
> 1) BusinessArea Business Areas pages:  when signed in should display
>   index
>        Failure/Error: expect(response).to render_template(:index)
>          expecting <"index"> but was a redirect to http://www.example.com/users/sign_in
>        # ./spec/requests/business_areas_spec.rb:21:in `block (4 levels) in '
>
> Finished in 0.17126 seconds (files took 2.24 seconds to load) 2
>   examples, 1 failure

It looks rather simple, but I don't get the point: why doesn't it log in?
Or is it another issue? Is the user actually created, how can I be sure FactoryBot is successful?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried using `byebug` in your `before ... do` block to see whether you're getting logged in or not?

Comment: Place a `byebug` right after the user's `create` and/or in the `sign_in` action. Testing factories: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/testing-your-factories-first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call the following helper method before the example runs, instead to call actual sign-in action.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-sign-in-and-out-a-user-in-Request-type-specs-(specs-tagged-with-type:-:request)

```rb
RSpec.describe BusinessArea, type: :request do
  include Warden::Test::Helpers

  context "when signed in" do
    before { login_as user, scope: :user }

    it "should display index" do
  end
```